# Repository of ArcView 3.x Avenue commands/methods/general information?

Tags: geoprocessing, arcview-3

The time has come for my great ArcGIS 10 skills to be put to the test... but we don't have readily available licenses for a lot of functionality that is exposed through ArcView 3.x's Avenue scripts. One pertinent example is the absolutely astounding [Shape].Flip functionality in the Field Calculation dialog that ArcView has that is only available to Medium-High license levels in ArcGIS 10. Long story short, I've decided it is worth knowing at least the basics of working with ArcView 3.x and Avenue. Where should I look?

I can't view the help because my OS cannot read .hlp files (yet).

Comment: Here is a good ESRI reference article for anyone wanting to tackle this: http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=20961

Comment: http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?sts=t&tn=arcview&x=0&y=0   an arcview search on Abebooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you at least see the old forum?
http://forums.esri.com/forums.asp?c=3
there are many threads there that will be of use and translating to Python is doeable.

Comment: Using this and Ryan Dalton's link, I was able to find exactly what I was looking for-- plenty of how-tos and reference guides. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't fret in the r10 modelbuilder window there is an import av3. I think that once you [dive into python](http://diveintopython.org/) you will find it's power is better than anything in av3x.
Here is some fairly old code that will do some of what you mentioned on the forum.
[flip polylines](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=74242)
Also [ian-ko](http://www.ian-ko.com/) has the et-Geotools which has many free tools including the flip tool.

Comment: That was one of the manuals I used to teach myself python, along with Thinking Like a Computer Scientist and Byte of Python.

Answer (score 1):

**Beyond Avenue - Using Python with ArcView 3.x**

> *After mastering the subtleties of VTab and FTab many ArcView users realize that Avenue alone can’t solve all of their challenges. Adding Python to the programmer’s toolbox can give ArcView access to the Internet, access to virtually any COM object with a published “IDispatch” scriptable interface, or perform other functions that just aren’t that easy to do with Avenue. This article will focus on a few examples and products that demonstrate the benefits of using Python and ArcView together.*

http://avpython.sourceforge.net/tutorial/

Comment: That... is absolutely awesome. I will definitely take a look at that. Thank you greatly!