# Switch line direction for PostGIS-lines in QGIS or Pgadmin

Tags: qgis, postgis, line

I am trying to switch the line direction in a PostGIS-layer. The postgis-geometry column is e.g. "LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2 1, 2 2)".

The reason is that my symbology is direction-dependent, but I drew some lines in the wrong direction.

I have tried using my usual approach that seems to only work for shapefiles. It is the code by Nathan W. that is in the answer that is linked below.

Link to similar question:

- [How can I switch line direction in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/how-can-i-switch-line-direction-in-qgis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If postgis resolution is also good maybe you're looking for [ST_Reverse](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Reverse.html) function