# change the direction of the marker of a line in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a map with three lines.  Each has a marker on it.

[image]

I would like to reverse the direction of the topmost marker.  So I open Style dialog and enter the expression `"direction" * 180`.  The value of direction of the topmost line is 1.  Others are 0.

[image]

The result is shown below.

[image]

Two issues here:

- The angles of all markers are the same.
- The direction of the topmost marker is not reversed.  (Is there a way to access a default value of 'Angle' property?)

Comment: You can turn the symbol by setting the angel into 180 in the Line - Marker line - Marker - Simple marker. The place is visible in your first screen capture. For using data defined properties there should be a field for that in the vector data for telling the angle.

Comment: @user30184 I'd like to reverse some markers (not all).

Comment: Sorry. I made a test shapefile with angle field as "double", I filled in values 0 and 1 and later also 0 and 180 and tried to make the data driven rotation to work. All my symbols seem to stay always at 0°, also SVG symbols. I can only confirm your issue.

Comment: I have managed to get it to work using one of the properties (i.e. $length), but of course with the limitation I couldn't get the base angle to add to a calculated bonus. I described a workaround as answer - requires a bit of python use though.

Comment: If you do not want to edit the data you can make two rule based styles for the lines: one for value "0" and another for "1". Then add marker lines to both styles. For the second one use marker editor and create a 180° rotated copy from the triangle2 marker.

Comment: @user30184 Thank you so much for your suggestion.  This is what I looked for.

Comment: @user30184 Please post your comment as an answer so this thread will be marked as answered

Answer (score 1):

It appears the easiest way (given I can't see a method to acces the property that holds the 'standard' marker rotation) is to reverse the actual line direction.

I'd suggest you use a Query to select all items where "direction" = 1 and then apply the method described [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/how-can-i-switch-line-direction-in-qgis)