# Rotating labels in QGIS 2.8.2

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-2.8

I have a question concerning label placement in QGIS. I'd like to rotate every label by 180°. Therefore, I set the rotation value to 180 (I've tried different ones as well as different variable types) according to the description:

[image: Current rotation settings]

I also applied every combination of "Preserve data rotation values" (what does that actually mean?) checked/unchecked and Rendering->"Show upside-down labels" (each value). But all this seems not to have any effect on the labels. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

For QGIS 2.8.2, it works fine. You can turn the labels upside-down:

[image: Line layer without labels]

To rotate labels by 180 degrees (or turn them upside-down), from the *Rendering* tab you can enable the option the **Show upside-down labels** option which would automatically rotate the labels. You don't need to define a value for 180 degrees:

[image: Make labels upside down]

Then that should do it. Remember that **6** and **9** will look like each other when upside down:

[image: Upside-down labels]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your effort! But I want to label lines and, consequently, the "Placement"-menu looks different. Nevertheless, I used the same settings as you describe them here (especially this "show always upside-down labels"-option)

Comment: @Johannes - It could be because you're using a different QGIS version. I did the exact same for a line layer and got the same results =)

Comment: Okay, now I am confused. The screenshot I posted above is looking quite different from yours. But it is from version 2.8.2-Vienna (I guess you just skipped the name "Vienna")

Comment: Yes, apologies, I skipped the name. In my version for Windows, it uses the German name (QGIS 2.8.2-Wien). I installed it through the [standalone installer](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html).

Comment: Actually, mine says 2.8.2-Wien as well. As far as I recall, I used the standalone installer. For sure, it is the Windows version, 64-bit.

Are you sure, you're labelling line features? I am confused about the options available for you concerning "centroid"

Comment: You're right, I forgot to change the images of the options. I've added the interface to show the QGIS version and the layer.

Comment: @Johannes: Note that Joseph's answer shows the Rendering section and not the Placement section.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, the rotation can only take effect if you also data-define the coordinates. Otherwise, labeling just follows the position defined in the placement section and ignores the data-defined settings.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds exhausting. Is there a(n easy) way to get the coordinates QGIS would determine automatically? (this is a line layer and I have not yet thought about determining the coordinates by hand...)

Comment: In a minimal example I could see that you remember properly: When setting X and Y manually as well, the label is flipped. I just wonder why it's working for Joseph...

Comment: Is this still the case for 3.8?

Answer (score 1):

Since I was not able to realize the rotation I did the following to achieve a comparable solution: I just switched the line direction ([How can I switch line direction in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/how-can-i-switch-line-direction-in-qgis)). This rotated the labels by 180°.

Comment: Very strange but atleast you found a solution =)