# QGIS 3x rotated label returns angle value instead of initial one

Tags: qgis

I would like to rotate the text value assigned to my point in QGIS.
For this purpose I used the following threads:

[Rotating labels in QGIS 2.8.2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153046/rotating-labels-in-qgis-2-8-2)
[QGIS Labels Rotation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298349/qgis-labels-rotation)

from which the best appears to be this one:

[https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232727/is-there-a-way-to-interactively-rotate-labels-in-qgis-using-any-of-the-edit-tool#:~:text=Yes%2C%20you%20can%20rotate%20labels,rotation%20using%20the%20label%20tools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232727/is-there-a-way-to-interactively-rotate-labels-in-qgis-using-any-of-the-edit-tool#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20you%20can%20rotate%20labels,rotation%20using%20the%20label%20tools).

Anyhow, I think I got the mechanism of rotation. Unfortunately, instead of presenting my initial values allocated to the given point, I am getting the angle value.

[image]

I would like to admit, that maybe my situation isn't as straightforward as in the given example, because I used the rule-based leveling, where I set the text character based on the "Visible" column in my data attribute table. The string still comes from the "Text" column, but the rule from the "Visible" column. Is that something, which might affect the rotation?
I've picked up the "Text" for the rotation rule. Shall I use the "Visible" variable then?

**UPDATE:**

Manual changing the label properties doesn't help at all.
When I put the right value, the angle immediately equals this value and other way round.

[image]

Is there a way to make the label value independent from the angle value?

Comment: Are you aware of the QGIS [EasyCustomLabeling Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/EasyCustomLabeling/)?

Comment: I somehow don't see what exactly you use as label for each of your rules.

Comment: This plugin doesn't help for me. It imports additional text layer and I have got "1" value under each string. How can I fetch it from Data attribute table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the settings of your rule based label set your label with your "Text" field

then to set the rotation in you label settings:
**Placement** -> **Data defined** -> **Rotation** set expression or field

(Sorry for the french ui but things should be at the same place)

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]