# Reverse polygon direction in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, direction

The following Python code is very helpful to reverse the direction of lines in QGIS:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
   geom = feature.geometry()
   nodes = geom.asPolyline()
   nodes.reverse() 
   newgeom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(nodes)
   layer.changeGeometry(feature.id(),newgeom)
```

(see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/9285/77061)

Unfortunately, the code doesn't work for polygons. Replacing `asPolyline()` and `fromPolyline(nodes)` with `asPolygon()` and `fromPolygon(nodes)` hasn't helped. Is there a Python code that works for polygons?

```
if layer.geometryType() == 2:
    # ?
```

Edit:

For PostGIS and most likely some other data providers it's possible to digitize polygons clockwise and counter-clockwise. Creating a marker line symbology (e.g. triangle) for such layer may result in inward and outward rotated markers. So I want to reverse the direction of the anti-clockwise digitized polygons through the Python console.

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as reversed polygon. Outer ring vertices go clockwise.

Comment: As far as I know, this depends on the data provider. In PostGIS it's possible to create polygon vertices clockwise and anti-clockwise.

Comment: Internal handling of polygons in QGIS is uniform as far as I know. Drivers turn direction when data are saved if needed.

Comment: Is it please possible to tell us why you want it?

Comment: Shapefile outer rings are clockwise; other data formats use left hand rule. If you succeed in flipping polygons to the incorrect orientation, you will likely cause random geometry manipulation failures. This goal is self-defeating.

Comment: @Miro Markers are rotated by 180 degrees if polygons are digitized counter-clockwise ('PostGIS data provider', 'New scratch layer'). I've added a screenshot.

Comment: So the issue is visualization - you want to achieve that all polygons will have same (outward/inward) direction of markers?

Comment: @Vince It doesn‘t matter if a shape polygon is digitized counter-clockwise or if the nodes are reversed through some Python code. In both cases the polygon direction is fixed when saving the edits. So shape files shouldn‘t be an issue.

Comment: So if you know it's not possible to intentionally mangle your data, what is the point of the question?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to clarify your problem and what you're trying to do.  Your comments I think are making this less clear.  Comments are for potential answerers to request more info or clarification, your response should be as edits to the question.

Comment: Have you tried saving everything out to a format that has only clock-wise or only counter-clock-wise polygons to enforce them all to draw the same way?

Comment: This is a good tip, but I was hoping for a Python based solution.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

This code works for polygons but, 'changeGeometry' method has no effect even in edit mode. It's necessary to create a new geometry as memory layer.

```
layer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()

new_geom = []

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feature.geometry()
    nodes = geom.asPolygon()
    print nodes
    nodes[0].reverse()
    print nodes
    new_geom.append(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(nodes).asPolygon())
    print layer.changeGeometry(feature.id(), newgeom)

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'polygon',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(new_geom)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(new_geom[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

polygon_memlayer = [ feat.geometry().asPolygon() 
                     for feat in mem_layer.getFeatures() ]

print polygon_memlayer
```

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS with this shapefile:

[image]

it could be observed, at Python Console, that the node order was effectively reversed.

[image]