# Finding the sequence/rank of lines (polylines) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qchainage

I have line shapefile with different bus routes (each route consist of multiple line), in which I want to sequentially arrange the lines for each bus route based on the direction of route.
I tried with QChainage, but couldn't achieve it.

Is it possible in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Could you go into more detail what you mean by "sequentially arrange"? How should the final result look like?

Comment: i have continuous lines as shown in attached image. in this i wanna rank the links based on each segment.. right now i have done it manually.
R_NB_1 (segment one), R_NB_2 (segment two) and goes on

Comment: Should be doable using pyqgis and networkx module if you are ok with some python?

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume there is a polyline layer `'lines_test'` with an imaginary bus route #1 (into town and from town), see image below

[image: input]

To get a sequence/rank of lines (polylines) in QGIS, there are couple of steps that can be followed.

**Step 1.** Use the ["Explode lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#explode-lines) geoalgorithm that will create line-strings out of the original continuous feature.

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Here use the ["Add autoincremental field"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#add-autoincremental-field) tool with `"Direction"` in the *Group values by*. It will sequentially arrange the lines for each bus route based on the direction of route.

[image: step_2_1]

and get the output:

[image: step_2_2]

If you are not satisfied with order of your vertices in some polylines use the [*ReverseLine*](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#reverse-line) [image: reverse_line] from the [Advanced Digitizing Toolbar](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/documentation_guidelines/substitutions.html#digitizing-and-advanced-digitizing). Other details you may find in this thread [Changing (flipping) line direction in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276403/changing-flipping-line-direction-in-qgis).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the QGIS plugin "Lines Ranking" can help you.
There is an [article](https://medium.com/swlh/the-algorithm-for-ranking-the-segments-of-the-river-network-for-geographic-information-analysis-b25cffb0d167) describing the algorithm.

You can check [repository with code](https://github.com/ChrisLisbon/QGIS_LinesRankingPlugin) also