# Applying offset to lines that are on top of each other, result like metro map

Tags: qgis, line, overlapping-features, offset, parallel-lines

As you can see from my picture there are a lot of places where the same lines run on top of each other. Imagine a tram map. How can I make sure that the ones that are behind are visible too?

[image]

Just like you see from metro or train maps:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must use categorized symbols, as you did.

Then you can edit each line symbol (double click on it to open symbol selector, then click on "simple line" for more properties) by giving a specific offset. Note that the offset is defined based on the direction of digitization (positive offset = right side), so you may need to [flip some lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276403/changing-flipping-line-direction-in-qgis) in order to have a nice result.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, but that would cause it to be the same offset on the whole line. But it's only on sections that it needs to offset (when there is another line). And sometimes it needs to switch to the other side depending on where the other line is coming from.

Comment: making a readable metro map is an art. I don't know any algorithm that would automatically select the best offset. Apart from moving (editing) the lines I don't see a solution in QGIS if you need to switch side (its possible to switch with an attribute field, but it will not look nice (i.e. no more connections)