# Changing MultiLineString direction using PyQGIS

Tags: line, pyqgis-3, direction, multipart

I am looking for a PyQGIS 3 method for reversing the direction of a `MultiLineString` feature. If there is more than one part, the order of the parts should be reversed.

I have found a similar question -
[Switching line direction in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/how-can-i-switch-line-direction-in-qgis) - for `LineString/Polyline` - which only works for QGIS 2 - and modified it slightly for use in QGIS 3.

However, I can't work out how to adapt the approach for `MultiLineStrings`.

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsGeometry

layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
feature = layer.getFeature(1) # feature id
geom = feature.geometry()
nodes = geom.asPolyline()
nodes.reverse() 
newgeom = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(nodes)
layer.startEditing()
layer.changeGeometry(feature.id(), newgeom)
layer.commitChanges()
```

In theory, the above approach could be used with

```py
newgeom = QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolylineXY(<QgsMultiPolylineXY>)
```

but I can't see how to generate the necessary `QgsMultiPolylineXY` object.

I have also noted the `reversed()` function on the `QGSMultiLineCurve` class, but I couldn't attach the generated `GSMultiLineCurve` to the original feature.

I'm not interested in UI-based approaches, as the features to be reversed are determined programmatically.

Comment: Do you also want to re-order the parts of multiline so that line1-line2-line3 would become line3reversed-line2reversed-line1reversed?

Comment: @user30184 - yes, have added clarification to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will focus on the geometry creation part, because the feature editing part is fully explained in many places, including the example inside the question.

I will use some Python list comprehension, but the key here is the use of the `QgsAbstractGeometry` type `QgsMultiLineString`, which is iterable and converts easily from/to list type.

From the QGIS API, you will see that each `QgsGeometry` is a container for the "real" `QgsAbstractGeometry`:

> A geometry is the spatial representation of a feature. Since QGIS 2.10, `QgsGeometry` acts as a generic container for geometry objects. `QgsGeometry` is implicitly shared, so making copies of geometries is inexpensive. The geometry container class can also be stored inside a `QVariant` object.
>
> The actual geometry representation **is stored as a `QgsAbstractGeometry`** within the container, and ***can be accessed via the `get()` method*** or set using the `set()` method.

```py
#First, will create an example multilinestring geometry
lines = [[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]],[[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]],[[0,2],[1,3],[2,4]]]
mls = QgsMultiLineString()
for i in [QgsLineString([QgsPoint(x,y) for x,y in i]) for i in lines]:
    _ = mls.addGeometry(i)

old_geometry = QgsGeometry(mls)

# QgsGeometry can be converted to QgsAbstractGeometry with the
# .get() method, so the real example begins HERE:

mls1 = old_geometry.get()
mls2 = QgsMultiLineString()
# For each reversed linestring, visited in reverse order
for i in [QgsLineString([*i][::-1]) for i in [*mls1][::-1]]:
    _ = mls2.addGeometry(i) # add it to new geometry

new_geometry = QgsGeometry(mls2)
old_geometry
#[out]: <QgsGeometry: MultiLineString ((0 0, 1 1, 2 2),(0 1, 1 2, 2 3),(0 2, 1 3, 2 4))>
new_geometry
#[out]: <QgsGeometry: MultiLineString ((2 4, 1 3, 0 2),(2 3, 1 2, 0 1),(2 2, 1 1, 0 0))>
```

Note here, that `QgsMultiLineString` objects are iterable so, you can expand it to a list of `LineString`s using `[*list]` Python syntax.

In the developer forum, they say it is recommended to use `QgsMultiLineString`, `QgsLineString`, `QgsPoint`,... etc when creating geometries, one advantage is the easy conversion from/to list conversion.

One thing to be aware of is that if you are using existing features, rather than a newly created one as per the example above, don't try to shortcut the "cloning" process. Given a feature `f`, use, for example:

```py
geom = f.geometry()
mls1 = geom.get()
```

rather than

```py
mls1 = f.geometry().get()
```

Otherwise, you will get a crash due to Python garbage collectin.