# TypeError when converting QgsMultiLineString to QgsGeometry using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, linestring, geometry-conversion, multipart

I have previously written some PyQGIS code to replace the features in a `LineString` layer with new features. The outline of the code is below - I have left out the specific code to create data for the `LineString`. This code works fine.

```py
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('LayerToChange')
layer = layers[0]
layer.startEditing()

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    ls = QgsLineString()

    #### Replace with code to populate LineString with data

    newgeom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(ls)
    layer.changeGeometry(f.id(), newgeom)

layer.commitChanges()
```

I am now looking to extend this to cater for `MultiLineStrings`. This seems straightforward enough, up until the point at which we need to create a `QgsGeometry` object from the `MultiLineString`.

```py
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry().constGet()
    mls = QgsMultiLineString()
    for l in geom:
        ls = QgsLineString()

        #### Replace with code to populate LineString with data

        mls.addGeometry(ls)
    newgeom = QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolylineXY(mls)
    
    layer.changeGeometry(f.id(),newgeom)
```

While `QgsGeometry.fromPolyline` will create a geometry from a `LineString`, `QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolylineXY` throws an error:

> ```
> TypeError: QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolylineXY(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsMultiLineString'
> ```

Can someone suggest a fix?

Comment: It looks like your question is covered by one of your previous [QGIS issue posted on GitHub](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/42612): `old_geometry = QgsGeometry(mls)`, init?

Comment: You've got a better memory than me ;). Though I did eventually find this question which helped me out: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313998/changing-multilinestring-direction-using-pyqgis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`QgsMultiLineString`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMultiLineString.html) is a child class of [`QgsAbstractGeometry`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAbstractGeometry.html) which can be used to create a `QgsGeometry` using the following constructor
[`QgsGeometry(QgsAbstractGeometry geom)`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a8c31d8d8b2a847c52e794d6db88a5485)

This means that you can replace:

```
newgeom = QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolylineXY(mls)
```

with:

```
newgeom = QgsGeometry(mls)
```