# How can I switch line direction from the Linux commandline?

Tags: shapefile, ogr, polyline-creation

I want to reverse the line direction for all lines in a shapefile from the Linux commandline (that is to say, using a script).  Currently I'm using the [SwapVectorDirection](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SwapVectorDirection/) QGIS plugin which works well but has to be run manually.  Ideally I'd like a solution using `ogr` since I have it installed on my system.

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/how-can-i-switch-line-direction-in-qgis) is similar but I'm looking specifically for something I can include in a Linux script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) utility with the `ST_REVERSE` function in a SQL statement and [OGR SQLite dialect](https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html):

For example:

```
ogr2ogr -dialect SQLITE -sql "select st_reverse(GEOMETRY), * from input" output.shp input.shp
```

Note: You need to pass in the `st_reverse(GEOMETRY)` first as the `GEOMETRY` field is [automatically selected if the * wildcard is used](https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html#geometry-field) and ogr will write only the first geometry out to a single geometry type layer.

Comment: Snap, I just figured that out, see edit.

Comment: Thanks, that works a treat.  The only tweak I had to make was to swap the columns in the query to be  `st_reverse(GEOMETRY), *`; without this I wasn't seeing any reversal.  BTW, with the aforementioned caveat the pre-edit version using `*` worked just fine with `ogr2ogr` from GDAL 2.2.3.  Presumably by putting the function first it overrode the default GEOMETRY column. I'll accept this answer in 24 hours unless a much better answer shows up.

Comment: Do you know if there's a list of all the supported spacial functions?  I took on the GDAL site and didn't see one.

Comment: Depends on the implementation and data source, but the OGC Simple Feature Access - Part 2: [SQL Option](https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfs) standard is the place to start

Comment: SQL dialect SQLite is using the spatial functions from SpatiaLite http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.