# QGIS change line start and end point

Tags: qgis

I have a line shp file from my friend, and want to use the QChainage to draw points every 10 km.
But the Start point and end point isn't right for me.

How can I change the Start point and End point? Search for a day and can't find the solution.

[image]

Comment: Do you simply want to flip the line direction, or do you need totally different points?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need the different point.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=qgis+change+line+direction&oq=qgis+change+line+direction&aqs=chrome..69i57.5743j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I switch line direction in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/how-can-i-switch-line-direction-in-qgis)

Answer (score 3):

Let's call the "original start point" P1, and the "new start point" P2.

Split the line at the new start/end point. Now you have two separate lines. Each line has one end at P1, and its other end at P2.

Now you need to move the P2 end point of one of the lines, so it's not directly on top of the other line's new starting point. Use the Vertex Editor tool for this. Make sure snapping is turned off.

`Dissolve` the two lines, and they will hopefully be one line which starts and ends at the new start and end points.

It's possible that the two lines didn't combine correctly. Here's how to test and trouble-shoot that. Run `split multipart to singlepart`. If the two lines are correctly combined, they won't split back into two separate features. If they do, you have one of these problems:

1. If the two lines are not going the same direction, they won't combine correctly. Select one line and run the "flip/reverse line" tool to reverse its direction (that's not the exact tool name, but it's something like that). Then dissolve the two lines together (one of the original lines with the reversed version of the other line).
2. If there was a gap between the original start and end point, the two lines won't combine correctly. Turn on snapping to vertices, then use the Vertex Editor tool to move the original start point of one line onto the original start point of the other line. Dissolve the two lines together again.

Answer (score 0):

What about change line direction? There is a button somewhere in edit tools.